Do any jurisdictions have laws that prevent people from passing taxes on to someone else?
Someone on the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange proposed replacing all taxes with a land tax, so that the poor would pay no tax because they don't usually own land. However, the obvious problem with that idea is that the majority of people and businesses who own land will provide some product or service, whose price they can then raise, thereby forcing the poorer consumers of that product or service to actually pay the tax. Indeed, as one commenter noted, "all taxes will eventually be passed on to someone who can't pass them on".
Do any countries have legislation that attempts to prevent this? That force people at whom the tax is aimed to take the hit from their income?

It is hard to imagine what that would even look like. The notion of passing taxes onto someone isn't meant literally, in most cases. It usually means that the economic effect is equivalent to doing so. So, passing taxes onto someone is model dependent upon the economic model used to determine tax incidence. It doesn't have a well-defined, model-independent reality.

How do you propose businesses pay tax if they don't pass the cost on to their customers?

@vidarlo "...force people at whom the tax is aimed to take the hit from their income." Businesses would simply make less profit.

I've voted to close. This is a kind of vague question. Yes businesses can raise prices but that lowers demand and lowers profits so it's all kind a bit kind of not really thought through and not very useful.

@PurpleP What if a business is at 0% profit, just paying salaries and expenses?

@ohwilleke Maybe that's true in a pure economic sense, but remember what happened when Trump imposed tarriffs. He said he was making the other country pay for dumping products on us. But these tariffs just ended up being paid by US businesses, who then raised their prices, and US consumers ended up paying for the tarriffs.

So the question seems to be asking if there's some way we can prevent this from happening. We want a specific entity to take the economic hit, not the consumers.

Taxes are often enacted to implement a social policy (e.g. carbon taxes to address climate change) and they can produce undesired consequences if the taxes is simply passed on.

I'd propose to modify your question to ask whether a government justified a law with the atempt to avoid the unjust passing-on of payment. That would take out the discussion about whether it worked in the end, which I agree has a certain vagueness to it.

I don't know if any such legislation exists (I doubt it), but the premise of your question is incorrect. In general, tax burdens fall on both producers and consumers in proportions which depend on the relevant supply and demand. In the specific case of a land tax, the burden is expected to fall entirely on landowners, as noted by Smith in 1776.

@CharlieEvans Adam Smith's economic theories from 1776 aren't exactly the state of the art in land tax incidence. But this does illustrate the reality that land tax incidence is not a settled point.

@ohwilleke Modern theory is in agreement with Smith, while more rigorous in its construction. What little empirical evidence exists also supports his contention.

I had to censor some personal attacks out of some of the comments above. Everyone, please remain civil and respectful.

@vidarlo Then it's clearly just not working hard enough, and it needs to sell its assets, find more revenue streams, increase its sales, and/or operate at a loss for a while. And if none of those work, the market has spoken and it deserves to fail. Isn't that what we tell poor people living paycheque to paycheque? Who end up having to pay the business's taxes?

In the end the customers pay the tax no matter how you bend it. What you're saying is just handwaving the question away - the corporation has to run a profit to pay taxes, e.g. extract more money from it's customers.

@vidarlo No, I am not handwaving the question away. A business receiving money from more entities/customers, be that through new revenue streams or sales to more customers, is not the same thing as it raising prices to extract more money from individual customers. Your weak rebuttal is only applicable to the second and third ideas I proposed in my previous comment; the first and fourth you have left totally unanswered. I neglected to mention "cut its expenses" as one of those points, but it is also not answered by your comment.

All this close-voting seems to be missing a major point.  Yes, it is a daft idea.  But... "oh, the corporations are just going to pass it on" is a recurring leitmotiv of both press coverage and individuals weighing in on such events.  A question, whether naive or not, that allows answers to identify how impractical stopping it would be in practice seems worthy, not unworthy.  +1 will vote to reopen.  Note that there is nothing all that opinion-based on either answers so far, they are pretty solid in actual practice, so the opinion-based reason to close is specious at best.

@vidarlo Look at it this way: imagine a tax is levied on, or a price of an essential item is raised for, a person living paycheque to paycheque. We don't tell them to pass taxes on, because that's beyond their abilities. We tell them to take out a loan, or get a second and/or higher-paying job, or sell their possessions, or cut unnecessary expenses. Your way of looking at things just sounds like typical corporate whining, claiming that the latest economic measure or labour right will bankrupt every business, something they have been doing for over a century.

@PurpleP Ultimately the person is passing the tax on to their customer, i.e. employer. I don't see how it's any different?

@vidarlo How?? That makes zero sense. The only way a person could pass a tax on is if, upon facing increased expenses, they were able to force their employer to raise their wages. Which people can't do, and which is why I have suggested that businesses should bear the burden instead.

Tax incidence is a matter that is highly dependent upon the economic conditions at any given time, primarily the price elasticity of producers and consumers of something that is taxed, that can vary considerably even without any change to the tax laws and who is legally responsible for making payments of the tax at any one time. See generally Wikipedia. As explained at this link:

Assessing tax incidence is a major economics subfield within the field
of public finance.
Most public finance economists acknowledge that nominal tax incidence
(i.e. who writes the check to pay a tax) is not necessarily identical
to actual economic burden of the tax, but disagree greatly among
themselves on the extent to which market forces disturb the nominal
tax incidence of various types of taxes in various circumstances.
The effects of certain kinds of taxes, for example, the property tax,
including their economic incidence, efficiency properties and
distributional implications, have been the subject of a long and
contentious debate among economists.
The empirical evidence tends to support different economic models
under different circumstances. For example, empirical evidence on
property tax incidents tends to support one economic model, known as
the "benefit tax" view in suburban areas, while tending to support
another economic model, known as the "capital tax" view in urban and
rural areas.
There is an inherent conflict in any model between considering many
factors, which complicates the model and makes it hard to apply, and
using a simple model, which may limit the circumstances in which its
predictions are empirically useful.

Tax incidence is also dependent upon one's economic model that the factors considered going into it. There is rarely full consensus on who really bears the full economic burden of any particular tax.
Tax laws and tax policies are normally not made by economists, however. Instead, they are made by elected officials and their political appointees, who rely on simpler rules of thumb that may or may not correspond to the economic reality.
For example, legislators most often assume that corporate income taxes are born by shareholders of the corporations taxed, that property taxes on rental real estate are born by tenants, and that gasoline taxes are born by end consumers of gasoline, even when there is economic literature suggesting otherwise. Legislators also tend to assume, on a partisan basis, that the economic burden of particular taxes is born by the person with the least political sympathy in their partisan coalition.
Whether or not tax laws are actually successful at forcing a particular class of people to bear the economic incidence of a particular tax doesn't have a consensus objective answer in most  cases, because it is model dependent.
Also, actual tax incidence is, in any case, a question for Economics.SE rather than Politics.SE. But while whether these efforts actually work is an economics question, what policy makers attempt to do to influence economic tax incidence is a politics question.
The example of windfall profits taxes
But, probably the most notable example of tax laws that are deliberately devised to have an economic impact on a particular class of taxpayers are windfall profits taxes, which try to focus the incidence of taxation on firms that suddenly see a rise in profits for reasons that are largely beyond their control:

A windfall tax is a higher tax rate on profits that ensue from a
sudden windfall gain to a particular company or industry.
There have been windfall taxes in various countries across the world,
including Australia, Italy, and Mongolia (2006-2009). During the
2021–2023 global energy crisis, policy specialists at the
International Monetary Fund recommended that governments institute
permanent windfall profits taxes targeted at economic rents in the
energy sector, excluding renewable energy to prevent hindering its
further development.

Windfall profits taxes are basically an attempt to exploit a loophole in the economic theory known as Coase theorem, which holds that in the long run "if the provision of a good or service results in an externality and trade in that good or service is possible, then bargaining will lead to a Pareto efficient outcome regardless of the initial allocation of property."
A corollary of the Coase theorem is that in the long run, economic markets and not the formal allocation of tax burdens, will end up determining who bears the economic burden of taxation.
A windfall profits tax attempts to short circuit that logic by applying only to short term changes in profits that arise before the market has time to adapt to them (in light of the relative elasticities of supply and demand for the relevant firms and consumers) and shift the economic burden from the firms that pay the tax to people who do business with them.
The example of the U.S. income tax exemption for municipal bonds
Another notable example of legislators considering tax incidence in writing tax legislation is the income tax exemption for interest on municipal bonds in U.S. tax law. In this case, legislators count on the people benefiting the exemption not receiving its true economic benefits, rather than the other way around.
Originally, this tax exemption was based upon a belief that state and local governments had sovereign immunity from federal income taxation. *See McCulloch v. Maryland, 17 U.S. 159, 210 (1819). See also Pollock v. Farmers' Loan & Trust Company, 157 U.S. 429 (1895). This theory has since been discarded as a matter of constitutional law. See generally, this 1969 law review article. But, based upon arguments made by economists, the tax break, which nominally mostly benefits wealthy investors, has not been repealed.
In this case, the conventional wisdom among policy makers is that even though the income tax exemption for municipal bond interest directly benefits high tax bracket individuals who invest in municipal bonds, that the economic incidence of the long term stable tax exemption inures predominantly to municipal governments in the form of lower interest rates for municipal bonds relative to the interest rates paid on corporate bonds from private companies that are similarly creditworthy.
This conventional wisdom is supported by the observation that the interest rate on municipal bonds is typically close to the interest rate on the highest credit rated corporate bonds reduced by the maximum marginal individual income tax rate on ordinary income (i.e. about 40% lower).
Since giving state and local government investments in infrastructure funded by municipal bonds a mild subsidy is a policy that has strong bipartisan political support, this policy has remained in the Internal Revenue Code of the U.S., even though ordinarily Democrats campaign on favoring a policy of taxing the rich more heavily and not less heavily as this tax exemption does.

Why not add your comment "It is hard to imagine what that would even look like."  That seems like the strongest indictment of this idea, as it's hard to see what would achieve that, except for intrusive price regulation.  Or windfall taxes.

Implicitly, yes. There are places that legally limit the amount of profits one can make, e.g. in the form price caps, at least in some sectors. (If you want a nearly random example, fuel prices have been in the news.) These can sometimes lead to insolvability of companies though.
Another method proposed, although less often implemented are "excess profits" taxes.
Neither of these is foolproof. The former relies e.g. on the assumption that the quality of the product cannot be lowered (while keeping the same price). This is one of the reasons why you're more likely to see them for energy than e.g. for construction materials.
The excess profits tax relies on accurately estimating the true cost of inputs, which can be a challenge in [deeply] vertically integrated structures that operate through many subsidiaries owned by the same group, even more so if they span multiple [tax] jurisdictions etc.
